# LCD displays garbage before restarting the power

Tags: avr, lcd, atmega16

this is a code that prints the word SMROO in the 4 lines , after uploading the project , this happens
[image]

but when I turn off the power then turn it on again it works well , it also works well on Proteus ,

```
void main(void)
{
    _delay_ms(2000);
    HLCD_voidInit4b();
    HLCD_voidGoToPosition(LCD_ROW_ONE, 1);
    HLCD_voidSendString("SMROO");
    HLCD_voidGoToPosition(LCD_ROW_TWO, 1);
    HLCD_voidSendString("SMROO");
    HLCD_voidGoToPosition(LCD_ROW_THREE, 1);
    HLCD_voidSendString("SMROO");
    HLCD_voidGoToPosition(LCD_ROW_FOUR, 1);
    HLCD_voidSendString("SMROO");
    while(1);
}
```

is this a solvable problem or should I accept that LCD is built like that ?

Comment: What is inside `HLCD_voidSendString`? How it works? Check electrical connections. Try to decrease output speed (increase output timings) etc.